# Highchart as a modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am currently working on a webpage with highchart. I need to show the same highchart as a modal on click of a button. I am using html bootstrap and javascript

This is what I have done

```
<div class="container" id = "container1" style = "width: 30%; height: 50%; margin: auto 0 0 0; position: relative; float: left"></div>
  <div class="container" id = "container2" style = "width: 30%; height: 50%; margin: auto 0 0 0; position: relative; float: left"></div>
  <div class="container" id = "container3" style = "width: 30%; height: 50%; margin: auto 0 0 0; position: relative; float: left"></div>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">click to zoom</button>
 <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
   </div>
  <div class="modal fade" role= "dialog" id = "myModal" style = "width: 50%; height: 70%; position: absolute; float: center">
 </div>
```

JS:

$(document).ready(function() {
            var title = {
               text: 'Cycle Profile'
            };
            var subtitle = {
               text: 'Source: cimtool'
            };
            var xAxis = {
               categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            };
            var yAxis = {
               title: {
                  text: 'Temperature (\xB0C)'
               },
               plotLines: [{
                  value: 0,
                  width: 1,
                  color: '#808080'
               }]
            };

```
        var tooltip = {
           valueSuffix: '\xB0C'
        }
        var legend = {
           layout: 'vertical',
           align: 'right',
           verticalAlign: 'middle',
           borderWidth: 0
        };
        var series =  [{
              name: 'Tokyo',
              data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,
                 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
           }, 
           {
              name: 'New York',
              data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 
                 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
           }, 
           {
              name: 'Berlin',
              data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6,
                 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
           }, 
           {
              name: 'London',
              data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 
                 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
           },
           {
              name: 'India',
              data: [5.9, 2.2, 7.7, 6.5, 13.9, 13.2, 14.0, 
                 14.6, 16.2, 8.3, 8.6, 6.8]
           }
        ];

        var json = {};
        json.title = title;
        json.subtitle = subtitle;
        json.xAxis = xAxis;
        json.yAxis = yAxis;
        json.tooltip = tooltip;
        json.legend = legend;
        json.series = series;

        $('#container1').highcharts(json);
        $('#container2').highcharts(json);
        $('#container3').highcharts(json);
        $('#container6').highcharts(json);
        $('#myModal').highcharts(json);
     });
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you go through the [Question Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and frame your question in a better way to reflect the problem. You can refer [this helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Please show us what you have tried and your sample code. Any how  I have created a fiddle including bootstarp and jquery aswell.

Where  you can see one button please click on that, it will open modal popup. That model contains high chart (basic line).

HTML :

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="container"></div> 



        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
});
```

[High chart as modal JS  Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ramkee/3c2ybgp9/3/)

Comment: Can you please tell me the above code is working for you ?

Comment: This one is fine but this is not what I am looking for may be you will understand if you check my example